# .NETCore Version errors (Netcoreapp 3.0)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   NU1202  El paquete Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 3.0.0 no es compatible con netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). El paquete Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 3.0.0 admite: netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)   BioHealthy  C:\Users\501.ACADEMICOS\Documents\GitHub\BioHealthy\BioHealthy\BioHealthy.csproj    1

¿How can i fix this? Pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error más común es que no estás usando aspnet3 core, ami me pasó algo similar pasando de aspnet core 2.x a 3.x y el error estaba en que el IDE no me dejaba usar aspnet core 3.0.

1. Actualiza el Visual Studio a la última versión.
2. usa el aspnet core 3.00 SDK.
   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
3. Cambia el proj para que compile usando aspnet core.

Por ahora aspnet core 3.x me ha gustado mucho en cuanto a performance pero es traumático actualizar.
(Si sigues con problemas rescribe para estar pendiente.)

Comment: Okay. Ya hice todo, compila y tal, pero ahora me dice: 

NU1202 El paquete Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.1 no es compatible con netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). El paquete Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.1 admite: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1) BioHealthy C:\Users\501.ACADEMICOS\Documents\GitHub\BioHealthy\BioHealthy\BioHealthy.csproj

Eso cuando quiero instalar Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Ok, Usas EntityFramework, puedes verificar si estás usando la vers para .3? mira en el xml del proyecto y quitale las vers.  Puedes enviar el xml?

Comment: Puedo hacer que todo pudiera funcionar efectivamente quitandole versiones de actaulizacion a los paquetes de Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer y Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Desing. Efectivamente todo marcha de maravilla ahora, gracias.

Comment: Salve gran Zevaneko. ( No olvides los puntos )